# How get Live Connect(Hotmail) Calendar Object ID.?

Tags: java, windows

I want to sync Hotmail Calendar with my Java web Application.(Not Android app).
Live Connect Dev suggests REST using below syntax.

GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/calendar.611afb17fa9448f28cdb8277e8ffeb77?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

where calendar.611afb17fa9448f28cdb8277e8ffeb77 is calendar's ID.

Can anyone tell me how to get calendar's ID.?

Thanks,

Ram

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is this question still valid or not, but i think will be good for documentation purposes.

before you call the detail of the calendar, you should list all calendar object first, by using

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/calendars?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

there then you'll get the list of calendar data.

**but don't be confused with CALENDAR or EVENTS**

you can get all list of events by using:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/events?start_time=2012-10-01T00:00:00Z
     &end_time=2012-10-03T00:00:00Z&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

good luck